# Check SQLiteException "extended" ResultCode in C# CLI App

Tags: c#, sqlite

i write an CLI App with SQLite support. For this i use the NuGet Pack "[System.Data.SQLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/1.0.108)" from SQLite Development Team.
All works fine, but how can ckeck the "[Extended Result Codes (Look at point 5)](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html)" in case of exception?

I can access all error codes in Enum SQLiteErrorCode but in "ex.ResultCode" is allways a [Primary Result Code (Look at point 4)](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html).

e.g.

```
try
{
    // DB actions ....
}
catch (SQLiteException ex)
{
    // This is what i want because is clear and easy to read
    if (ex.ResultCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Constraint_Unique)
    {
        Debug.Write("SQLiteError: " + ex.Message);
    }

    // This works, but is not nice
    if (ex.ResultCde == SQLiteErrorCode.Constraint && ex.Message.Contains("UNIQUE"))
    {
        Debug.Write("SQLiteError: " + ex.Message);
    }

    throw ex;
}
```

Can anybody help me for this?

Comment: The silence means it's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature was added since the version 1.0.70.0 :

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

> 1.0.70.0 - April 22, 2011
>
> Added support for sqlite3_extended_result_codes(), sqlite3_errcode(),
> and sqlite3_extended_errcode() via SetExtendedResultCodes(),
> ResultCode(), and ExtendedResultCode(). Added support for
> SQLITE_CONFIG_LOG via SQLiteLogEventHandler().

To use it:

```
conn.Open();
conn.SetExtendedResultCodes(true);
```

and you can catch the exception:

```
if (ex.ResultCode == SQLiteErrorCode.Constraint_Unique)
{
Debug.Write("SQLiteError: " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Better late then never . Thx vor this answer.